# Does the in-app Safari browser support cookies for affiliate links?

Tags: ios, cookies, safari

I have a mobile app, which is linking to Amazon products within the in-app Safari browser (so that the user will stay inside the application), but I don't know if this in-app browser supports cookies, which is needed for an affiliate link to work.

If it doesn't support cookies by default, can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

It does, yeah. You should set

```
[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookieAcceptPolicy = 
NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways;
```

to make sure that it always uses cookies if that's what you want.

Comment: You can do it in the Application Delegate's "applicationDidLaunch" method. That's the best place to do it to ensure that it's done before any UIWebViews are made. Also, the in-app browser (UIWebView) isn't Safari, Safari is much faster because they use something called the Nitro engine (which in iOS 8, you can now access using a special webview (WKWebView)...

Comment: Aha, okay thanks. I will definitely need to look closer into this.

Comment: The problem is that UIWebview cookies are not shared with Safari. So if your user later on uses Safari to buy the product, your cookie is not read. Besides the cookies, Amazon might use some "fingerprint technique" to still assign the sale to you, but you need to test that. Maybe WKWebView will change that, i'll check it out.

Comment: Third party cookies in safari are blocked so that won't help much: https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/